# Odd entry in 'Top network posts' for a user

Tags: bug, profile-page, top-network-posts

I've loaded the meta.se profile for a [user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/282094/rob) and noticed that there's something decidedly odd about one of the entries in their Top network posts:

[image: Top network posts showing a title free post]

The blank space is hyperlinked to https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/-2147482202/147341#147341 - which also looks strange as there's a negative number for the question id and no URL slug. As numbers go, it's rather close to the lowest number that SQL/C# will store as an Integer, but also not *quite* there...